# Machine Learning using python related to time series

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I working on dataset consisting of time series including columns for `Amount` and various other variables. I want to group columns based on the year and quarter year and then aggregate those columns using `Amount` in those specific time line. The syntax is given below

```
ts_quarter = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.quarter).agg({'AmountInUSD'})['AmountInUSD']
```

It give the folowing errors:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It would really help for us to see your data

Comment: Check your datatypes and convert them to int or float.